# How can custom underline to a text

Tags: css

How to get border-bottom like in image. I've tried text-underline for a `h1` tag using `text-decoration` property.

[image]

```css
h1 {
  color: #F16A70;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30;
  font-family: oswald text-decoration: underline;
}
h1:after {
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one more solution:

```css
h1{
    color: #F16A70;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30;
    font-family: oswald;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70);
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 2px;
    transition: background-size .5s ease;
}
h1:hover {
    background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Animation of `:after` pseudo-element - to get it visible you need to set position attribute for both `h1` and `h1:after`:

```css
h1 {
    color: #F16A70;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30;
    font-family: oswald;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 30%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
h1:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to this:

```css
.navigation-heading h1 {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color: #F16A70;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'oswald';
}

h1:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  width:65%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-heading">
  <h1>navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work for multiline underlining :(

Answer (score 2):

> You can do it with css3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

**Steps:**

1. Create background image with `linear-gradient()`.
2. Adjust its size with css `background-size` property.
3. Place it at the bottom left position of the element with `background-position` css property.

**Necessary CSS:**

```
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 60% 3px;
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 60% 3px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  color: #F16A70;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1{
   color: #F16A70;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 30;
   font-family: oswald
   text-decoration: underline;
}

h1:after{
  display: block;
  width:20%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flexbox` and `:after` pseudo-element.

```css
h1 {
  color: #F16A70;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1:after {
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<h1>navigation</h1>
```

You can also use `relative/absolute` positions to position pseudo-element.

```css
h1 {
  color: #F16A70;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1:after {
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F16A70;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1:after {
    content : "";
    width   : 50%;  /* you can set here the length of border */
    border-bottom:1px solid #f16a70;
}
```

Update `h1:after` css